# How to insert this block of text using Vim?

Tags: vim

I'm a Vim beginner and I'd like to know how an experienced Vim user would input this block of Haskell code (from http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions):

```
sayMe :: (Integral a) => a -> String  
sayMe 1 = "One!"  
sayMe 2 = "Two!"  
sayMe 3 = "Three!"  
sayMe 4 = "Four!"  
sayMe 5 = "Five!"  
sayMe x = "Not between 1 and 5"
```

I'd imagine one could write the "sayMe" and "=" last using some sort of column operation (visual mode?).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Writing character by character? You could save some keystrokes but by yanking and pasting lines but I doubt it's worth it when you are a fast typist anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start with this:

```
sayMe 1 = ""
```

Now in normal mode do `qwYp^Aq4@w` (note that `^A` is a single character, control-A). The result will be:

```
sayMe 1 = ""
sayMe 2 = ""
sayMe 3 = ""
sayMe 4 = ""
sayMe 5 = ""
sayMe 6 = ""
```

Then I have a useful map (in my opinion):

```
nnoremap Q $i
```

This enters insert mode before the last character. So I go inserting the
quote contents (subsequent  lines, after moving down will  be already at
last character, so a simple `i` is  enough). Also, in the last, I change
`6` to `x` with a simple `F6rx` after entering the quote contents.

```
sayMe 1 = "One!"
sayMe 2 = "Two!"
sayMe 3 = "Three!"
sayMe 4 = "Four!"
sayMe 5 = "Five!"
sayMe x = "Not between 1 and 5"
```

Then `ggO` to  go to top and  `^E` multiple times to  insert bottom line
content, until the colons. That part onwards just regular typing.

```
sayMe :: (Integral a) => a -> String
sayMe 1 = "One!"
sayMe 2 = "Two!"
sayMe 3 = "Three!"
sayMe 4 = "Four!"
sayMe 5 = "Five!"
sayMe x = "Not between 1 and 5"
```

I hope this helps. Just an idea.  You can get fancier with a `:s//\=` to
auto insert the numbers, but I think  this would be faster (to me) since
it is only a few lines.

Comment: Hi, thank you for showing me this. I have learned much from your demonstration of a macro.

Comment: @Derek Hello! Happy to help. I didn't explain in much detail but I see you got it. Thanks :-)

Comment: Actually `qwYp^Aq4@w` doesn't work because of `A`, and without `A` it is just copying the line without modification and that can be done with much simpler `Y5p`.

Comment: Hello @Andrey `^A` is a single character, means control-A there is no `A` in my macro

Comment: Oh, I see, nice trick. Could you update the answer with this clarification?